# Brass/plastic part to keep toilet seat lid from lying back too far

Tags: toilet, fitting

I have at times seen toilet seats fitted with what could be called a backstop that prevents the seat lid from resting against the toilet tank lid or otherwise traveling too far back. I've seen them on older (*or retro*) toilets, with brass hinges (*though a strong plastic would be fine*).

I've been looking for something like that, but I can't find anything, in stores, or online. Heck, I don't even know what the correct name is.

I need something like that to prevent the seat lid on the toilet in my master bathroom from resting against the flush lever, which restrains it from allowing the flapper to close.

Does anybody know what the name of that part  is, Or keywords to uses, so i may have better luck in my search?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried all kinds of search terms with no luck.

I would suggest that you affix something  to the tank that the seat will rest against instead of the flush handle. It would need to be thick enough to stop the seat before it reaches the handle (*and not so thick that the seat will not stay up*)

Perhaps a nice piece of foam wrapped in some material that matches your decor or towels.

You could use some light duty hook and loop fastener (*Velcro*) on it and the tank to affix it so you could remove it form washing it and cleaning the toilet.

If it proves to be successful then we can advertise it with late night TV infomercials and make millions.

- (*Actually we could do that regardless of whether it works or is even necessary and still make millions as long as we speak loudly and with conviction*)

**OR** You could even just place something on top of the tank thick enough to stop the seat before it reaches the handle (*and not so thick that the seat will not stay up*) like a decorative box to hold potpourri or scented matches or grandma's toilet paper cozy.

Comment: Down vote? Pourquoi?

Comment: I don't know why the comment should have been downvoted.  It is obviously not what I wanted to hear, but then sometimes that's just the way it goes.  I had attached a rubber bumper to the toilet tank lid, but it isn't the best-looking solution.  But the tank lid cover idea isn't bad.  I may get my son to make one for me.